# How let know for parent fragment, that child fragment list item selected

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

App has ***Viewpager*** that has four tab with ***fragment***. Second fragment has framelayout "frame_layout" where I put fragment with listview. And when user click listview item opened new fragment with listview in this framelayout "frame_layout" and and so on.

How let know for parent fragment, that child fragment list item selected